# VSCode - TSLint extension triggers without config file

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I started working on a TS project and the TSLint extension seems to trigger with some default rules. The workspace setup is as follows:

```
project/
|-dir-x/
| |-file-a.ts
| |-tslint.json
|-dir-y/
  |-file-b.ts
```

Now `file-a`.ts is validated according to the respective `tslint.json`, which is fine. But `file-b.ts` is also validated, according to... something? Where can I find default TSLint settings, or is there something wrong with my setup? There is only the one `tslint.json` in the entire directory structure.

I should mention that `file-b.ts` is *not* validated against the other `tslint.json`, as the rules don't match. For example, the `tslint.json` has `quotemark` set to `true`/`single`, but in `file-b.ts` it complains about single quotes and says that it should use double quotes instead.

In the TSLint settings I can see the `Config file` option, which is left blank for me.